# Custom "prefix" delimiter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

Can I change route delimiter when I'm using "prefix" from "/" to "-"

So this route looks like: "`categories/test`"

```
Route::prefix('categories')->group(function (){
    Route::get('test');
});
```

Can I change it to "`categories-test`" with prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can probably not do this using the prefix function, because it [has the slash hardcoded](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L627). However Route is Macroable so you can write your own.

```
Route::macro(‘dashPrefix’, function ($name) {
    $uri = rtrim($prefix, '/').'-'.ltrim($this->uri, '/'); // note the '-'
    $this->uri = trim($uri, '/');
    return $this;
});
```

A place where you could add this code is `boot()` of **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider**. And use it like

```
Route::dashPrefix('categories')->group(function (){
    Route::get('test');
});
```